# ERD to Relational schema

Tags: database-design, relational-theory, erd

[image: .]

I'm new to DBM and I'm trying to learn it online. Honestly, I need some help with this. I don't know if I'm doing this right, and any help will be appreciated. This is my answer for i.
[image]

Comment: There are many comprehensive resources online. [Eg.](http://opentextbc.ca/dbdesign/) Textbooks and univeristy slides. (Eg at stanford.edu & sfu.ca .)

Comment: Where did you get this exercise? What is particular kind of ER/EER? How do they expect to map to a schema?

Answer (score 2):

There should be a table for every box, ie entity type/class, and every diamond, ie relationship type/class. There should be a column for every oval, ie attribute/property. Each line from a diamond to a box is indicates a foreign key. Relationship PKs are composite and consist of FK columns to associated/participant/referenced entity types.